# Method with return value as boolean

Tags: c#, interop, user32

I have the below code where ShellExecuteEx return a boolean value true or false when executed. And i am assigning that to a class level variable by converting it to string.

```
strShellCallStatus = ShellExecuteEx(ref info).ToString();

[DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern bool ShellExecuteEx(ref SHELLEXECUTEINFO lpExecInfo);

public static void exev()
{
    SHELLEXECUTEINFO info = new SHELLEXECUTEINFO();
    info.cbSize = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(info);
    info.lpVerb = "open";
    info.lpFile = "c:\\windows\\notepad.exe";
    info.nShow = 5;
    info.fMask = 0x440;
    info.hwnd = IntPtr.Zero;
    strShellCallStatus = ShellExecuteEx(ref info).ToString();
}
```

Should I concern about ShellExecuteEx returning null value ? If so I want to use the below statement:

```
strShellCallStatus = Convert.ToString(ShellExecuteEx(ref info));
```

Comment: How can a `bool` be `null`?

Comment: Why do you need a NULL-value to be returned, either it should be executed or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as `ShellExecuteEx` signature is not `bool? ShellExecuteEx()`, you shouldn't be scared that it will return `null` because `bool` is a value type with a default `false`.

Simply - a method with signature `bool ShellExecuteEx()` cannot return `null` cause it wouldn't even compile.